# Reading a text file and assigning certain lines to certain variables

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm working on a Trivia C# console game which reads a text file  that has a question , answer multiple choices ,the number of the correct choice and answer explanation.There is four question sets .The task is to prompt each question in the file to the console window ,have the user enter the answer  then compare the user's answer with the correct one.That should be done for all four questions in the file.

A class that includes question ,multipleAnswewrChoice,correctAnswer and answerExplanation has been created with getters and setters for each field .

What I'm struggle with is how after reading the file ,to assign each question to a certain variable in order to prompt it to the user and also to do this for four sets.
I made an array of size 4 (as I have 4 lines for each question set) to store the lines then assigned each element to each variable above ,but I couldn't figure out how to loop to do the same for all four sets.

The QuestionUnit is the class that contains the question fields.

```
 public void ReadQuestionFile( QuestionUnit unit)
        {
            string[] arrayReader = new string[4];
            string line = "";
            int i = 0;
            string fileName = "TextFile1.txt";
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
            while ((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null && i < 4 )
            {

                arrayReader[i] = line;
                // Console.WriteLine(line);

                //Console.WriteLine(arrayReader[i]);
                i++;

            }
           unit.M_Question  = arrayReader[0];
            unit.M_Answers = arrayReader[1];
            unit.M_CorrectAnswers = arrayReader[2];
            unit.M_Explanation = arrayReader[3];


        }
```

Any ideas about how to do this ?

Comment: share some code

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: My code is distributed between four classes ,am actually not sure how to share it here .

Comment: " I made an array of size 4 (as I have 4 lines for each question set) to store the lines then assigned each element to each variable above ,but I couldn't figure out how to loop to do the same for all four sets." Well, show us the declarations for a start and how you fill them..

Comment: Having an array that stores the first 4 strings after read it from a file ,now how to have the same array to store the next 4 lines ?That is all what I can figure out.

Comment: I mean *can't figure out !

Comment: I did share the code ,any ideas now ??!!

Comment: Thank you for posting your code, I (and others I am sure) will look it over and post something when we determine what the solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all your data is in the same file, your going to need to take a slightly different approach. Instead of passing in the item to fill out, I would have the function return the list of read questions:

```
public IEnumerable<QuestionUnit> ReadQuestionFile()
```

Then, read in a loop until you reach the end of the file. This approach is NOT safe for invalid input, so be careful:

```
string fileName = "TextFile1.txt";
List<QuestionUnit> readQuestions = new List<QuestionUnit>();
using (StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    while (!myReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        QuestionUnit newQuestion = new QuestionUnit();
        newQuestion.M_Question  = myReader.ReadLine();
        newQuestion.M_Answers = myReader.ReadLine();
        newQuestion.M_CorrectAnswers = myReader.ReadLine();
        newQuestion.M_Explanation = myReader.ReadLine();

        readQuestions.Add(newQuestion);
    }
}
return readQuestions;
```

Basically, you read until the end of the file, reading four lines at a time. You'll get some null values if the input format isn't correct. You don't really need an array here since you can store the values directly in your object, which you then add to the list when you are done populating it (technically you could have done it before as well). Then you return the filled out list to whatever uses it.

You could possibly use a `yield return` instead of directly adding to a list, but that is a bit of an advanced concept for starting out, and I'm not sure how well it would mesh with the File I/O. It is good to be aware of its existence either way. The only change would be the removal of `readQuestions`, and the line:

```
yield return newQuestion;
```

where the call to `Add` currently is.

Let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: So you are returning an array list which has all the lines in the file ?And can loop around this array list prompting some of its elements to the user ?Did I get that right ?

Comment: Basically, though I am not, and would not recommend, using an ArrayList. I'm using a List<T> (from System.Collections.Generic).

Comment: Oh sorry ,you are returning an array list that has objects .Right ?

Comment: I'm not returning an ArrayList at all, I'm returning the generic type `List<T>` (typed to QuestionUnit). The implementation actually doesn't matter, I just used `List` because it was convenient. The fact that it is an IEnumerable is what matters here. ArrayList is considered bad practice in .NET 2+ (when the generic collections were introduced). It holds `QuestionUnit` objects (which do inherit from object) but it is strongly typed to `QuestionUnit`.

Comment: Yes ,got you .Now should I loop 4 times around the collection ?

Comment: Presumably. You could also just use a foreach, put the questions into a Queue (instead of a list) and do a while until the queue is empty (Dequeuing after each question of course) and probably a couple other things. Its up to you, this code just returns all the question data in a list.

Comment: Thank you so so so  much ! Seriously appreciate your help !

Comment: Not a problem, glad I was able to help. Thank you for responding to the comments and posting your code, it was very helpful when writing my answer.